# How to automatically fetch the active Docker registry

Tags: bash, docker

I am delivering a Docker image along with a script to automate and build > push that image to the repository.

```
docker build -t myDockerSpace/myServiceImage:latest .
docker push myDockerSpace/myServiceImage
```

without specifying the namespace/hub I run into access issues. Anyhow issue is when I delivery these scripts I would need to ask them to manually change the hub to their respective registry and then run which actually kills the purpose to automate it.

Is there a way I can fetch and insert the active Docker namespace of the machine where it is running and insert it in the document?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here. The `myDockerSpace` should be a DNS accessible domain name. The only preparation the customer would need to do is to sign into the registry (unless it is a public registry).

Comment: @halfer yes, but `myDockerSpace ` would be different for me and different for the client. So the question is how can i use a variable or dynamically assign value to fetch the default namespace user of the machine where it is running. So, they dont need to manually change anything, instead just run the script.